# desktop nav bar sticky top to mobile nav bar sticky bottom

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm using [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com) as my CSS framework

Currently I have a nav bar that sticks to the top in PC desktop view (i.e., the page scrolls under it). Here's the code:

```
<div style="height:50px">
 <div id="fixed-nav-bar">
  <div class="container" id="nav">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>



#fixed-nav-bar {
      position:fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 9999;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background-color:linen;
  }

#nav ul {
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
  }

#nav ul li {
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
  }
```

My Question: How can I make it so that when viewing it in a mobile device (i.e. a phone), the nav bar moves to the bottom (to be easily usable in one-handed mode) and stays sticky?

I'm guessing I need to use media queries. How can I use them here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution: with `bottom:0;` you get your `#fixed-nav-bar` to the bottom of page. Just replace 960px with select width of device you wont `#fixed-nav-bar` to go to bottom.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    #fixed-nav-bar {
        top: inherit;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to this: http://getskeleton.com/#queries you should design with 'mobile-first' principle in your mind. So actually `top: 0;` should be applied to screens with `min-width` > x

Comment: I take look, you're right. He will need to do it reverse.